# What could cause a YouTube Video ID to change?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

April 19th I created a private video, edited it a few times natively, and made it public on the 20th. Each time that I edited it and when I published it its ID changed, leading to a process I have managing my videos interpreting it as several different videos. After the update, there is no object with the previous object ID returned from the googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems endpoint.

I have attempted to recreate this on other videos since then, however I cannot seem to. Are there certain types of updates which would lead to the entire video being recreated? Could this be a bug in the API?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by *edited it a few times natively*? Could you also precise how you *published it*? To be precise, by *object ID* you mean [PlaylistItem: id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#id), right?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison By _edited a few times natively_ I mean that our client modified the video through YouTubes client directly instead of via the API. Best I can tell, this was their flow:
They created a private video. They updated the title of the video, which changed the id and permalink of the video. They updated the title and description, as well as the privacyStatus of the video to unlisted, which did not change the id. They updated the description again, which changed the id and permalink of the video. They updated the description again, which changed the id and permalink of the video.

Comment: Also, by _object id_ I did mean [PlaylistItem: id](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#id), thank you

Comment: If you are able in the future to reproduce this issue step-by-step, then this should be reported, otherwise it may just be a one-time bug which isn't much interesting.

Comment: @RyanZappulla could you share the IDs of such videos?

Comment: They were: HWx--YL3Q5s, qHQM_FaDLH4, o4GwsGxeN6c